# Tempo tables used on queries running at the same time throwing already exists error

Tags: postgresql, create-table, temp, drop

I'm running multiple queries (in diffent sessions) which use the following code, some times in paralell, and I was getting errors saying the temp table already existed. I was under the impression the temp tables would just be using some sort of random name in the background processing so these don't interfiere with each other:

```
select country_id, product_category_id, sum(units) as total_units
into temp totals
from schema.table
group by country_id, product_category_id;
```

I'm getting this:

> Query failed: ERROR: relation "totals" already exists.

Postgres version is 9.4 and **this only happens when using pgbouncer port**

Am I doing something wrong? Should I use create temp table instead?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe you have a regular table named `totals`? Btw: it is recommended to use the standard compliant `create table .. as select` rather than the Postgres specific `select .. into ... from ..`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: I checked and the table totals only exists on pg_temp_NNNN schemas

Comment: Are you maybe running that statement more than once in a session? The default is to keep temp tables until the session (=connection) is closed.

Comment: I just noticed this happens only when using the pgbouncer port, I'll add this to the querstion

Answer (score 0):

It was the pgbouncer set up, we had the pool_mode as *transaction*, once we changed it to *session* it worked OK